# Issue with promotion impressions and clicks on Gooogle Tag Manager Android

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to implement promotion impression on my app, following the Google's documentation for enhanced e-commerce on GTM for android:

https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v5/enhanced-ecommerce

I'm having issues with promo impressions and promo clicks.

When I was using the 17.2.2 version of the Firebase SDK, everything worked as expected, I was able to send the events and get them to appear on my App view from Google Analytics (Universal Analytics)

But when I upgraded to the SDK version 17.5.0, I get an error when trying to log the promo view and promo click events.

I'm getting error code 20 for view_item event, saying that the "promotions" name is invalid

https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/errors

[error code 20](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RE3tV.png)

[error value promotions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9duY.png)

I'm following the documentation provided, but I keep getting this error with sdk version 17.5.0, but not with sdk version 17.2.2

Here's the part of the code that I'm using

```
// Define promotion with relevant parameters

Bundle promotion = new Bundle();
promotion.putString( Param.ITEM_ID, "PROMO_1234" ); // promotion ID; either ITEM_ID or ITEM_NAME is required
promotion.putString( Param.ITEM_NAME, "Summer Sale" ); // promotion name
promotion.putString( Param.CREATIVE_NAME, "summer_banner2" );
promotion.putString( Param.CREATIVE_SLOT, "banner_slot1" );

// Prepare ecommerce bundle

ArrayList promotions = new ArrayList();
promotions.add(promotion);

Bundle ecommerceBundle = new Bundle();
ecommerceBundle.putParcelableArrayList("promotions", promotions );

// Log view_item, view_item_list, or view_search_results event with ecommerce bundle

mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(Event.VIEW_ITEM, ecommerceBundle );
```

Also tried the new e-commerce events for firebase, but it only worked in the app+web property, even though I've created a tag for this event on GTM.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/measure-ecommerce#apply_promotions

Can anyone give me a hand with this please?

Thanks

Comment: I'm also having the same issue but on iOS. Any updates on this?

Comment: @SilentK I've opened an issue on firebase github for android. Here's the link [Issues with Promo impressions and clicks (for Universal Analytics) on SDK version 17.5.0](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/2075). From the answers that I got, to keep using the UA Ecommerce events, the SDK must be in a version lower than 17.5.0 (and the equivalent for iOS)